# Relation between Eigenspaces and Direct Sum

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to prove what follows: Given the distinct eigenvalues $\{\lambda_1,...,\lambda_p \}$ of the Matrix $A$, the eigenspaces $E_{\lambda_i}$ have the following property of the direct sum: for all vectors $u_i\in E_{\lambda_i}$ it follows  $$ \sum_{i=1}^p u_i=0 \implies u_1=u_2=...=u_p=0. $$

I am trying to prove it by induction: for $p=1$ it is trivial. For $p>1$, it is clear that the equality $\sum_{i=1}^p u_i=0 $ leads to $A(\sum_{i=1}^p u_i)=\sum_{i=1}^p Au_i=\sum_{i=1}^p \lambda_i u_i=0.$ By multiplying the first equality by $\lambda_p$, and following substraction by the second one i get: $$ \sum _{i=1}^{p-1} (\lambda_i-\lambda_p)u_i=0.$$ Now i should use the hypothesis of the induction but i am somehow stuck. Can somebody give me a hint, how to conclude the proof, and eventually state if/why this theorem is important. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The vectors

$$v_{i}\equiv\left(\lambda_{i}-\lambda_{p}\right)u_{i}\in E_{\lambda_{i}}$$

for $1\leq i\leq \color{red}{p-1}$ form a set of $\color{red}{p-1}$ vectors such that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\color{red}{p-1}}v_{i}=0$$

Comment: The second hint is to recall that the $\lambda_i$s are distinct.

Comment: @user296113 Of course! Thanks for the important comment!

Comment: Thanks.I was confused with the indices: i wanted the conclusion to follow the passage $p$ to $p+1,$ whereas the intermediate result i got  involved only $p-1.$ So, to follow your suggestion, $\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} v_i=0 \implies v_1=v_2=...=v_{p-1}$  would be the restatement of the induction hypothesis. Thus,  $\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} v_i+v_p=0 \implies v_p=0$. Is it correct ?

Comment: @user249018 Almost! $v_{1}=v_{2}=\dots=v_{p-1}=0$ leads to $u_{1}=u_{2}=\dots=u_{p-1}=0$ because the eigenvalues are distinct and you can divide by $\lambda_{i}-\lambda_{p}\neq 0$. Now you substitute it back into the sum to get $$u_{p}=\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}u_{i}+u_{p}=\sum_{i=1}^{p}u_{i}=0\Longrightarrow u_{p}=0$$ as wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the help.